# How to create the function to give that result

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The function that will take over all the arguments needs to be created, and I don't understand what part of [1].a(3)

```
const add = () => {

}
add(1)(2)[1].a(3) // 1+2+3 = 6
```

Comment: I honestly do not understand your question. The function you describe doesn't make any sense to me... What is it that you want? What kind of result do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const add = (first) => {
  return (second) => {
    return [
      undefined,
      {
        a: (third) => first + second + third
      }
    ];
  }
}

let result = add(1)(2)[1].a(3);
console.log(result);
```

:)